# active state for Jquery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my accordion with Jquery, and I want only the opened selection to have the active icon, but at the moment my function apply it to all selections.

Can someone see where the problem is?

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jcuuc3e7/

Code:

```
 <div id="accordion">
   <div class="accordion-segment">
      <a class="accordion-open" href="#samarbejdspartnere">
          <h3>Samarbejdspartnere</h3>
          <svg class="accordion-icon" width="13" height="8">    
              <path d="M13.6,1.6L12,0L6.8,5.2L1.6,0L0,1.6l6.8,6.8L13.6,1.6z M13.6,1.6"/>
          </svg> 
      </a>
      <div>
          <ul class="accordion-content">
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Stuff</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Stuff</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Stuff</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-segment">
      <a class="accordion-open" href="#nyheder">
          <h3>Nyheder</h3>
          <svg class="accordion-icon" width="13" height="8">    
              <path d="M13.6,1.6L12,0L6.8,5.2L1.6,0L0,1.6l6.8,6.8L13.6,1.6z M13.6,1.6"/>
          </svg>
      </a>
      <div class="accordion-content">
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Nyhed 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Nyhed 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Nyhed 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Nyhed 4</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        heightStyle: "content",
        animate: 250,
        header: "a"
    });
});

$(".accordion-open").click(function() { 
    var accIcon = $(".accordion-icon");

    accIcon.each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("accordion-icon-active");
    });

    if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
       accIcon.addClass("accordion-icon-active");
    }    
});


.accordion-segment { 
    width: 400px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $oslo-gray; 
}

.accordion-open { 
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.accordion-icon {
    width: 13px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: auto;
    fill: red;
    transition: .25s ease;
}

.accordion-icon-active { 
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transition: .25s ease;
}

.accordion-content { 
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: I think you should do :`if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
       $(this).find('.accordion-icon').addClass("accordion-icon-active");
    } `

Comment: Ye it works:P Thank you. Any comments on what went wrong, so I can better understand my mistakes :):)

Comment: You weren't targeting the clicked item. `$(".accordion-icon");` is an array of objects in your example. `$(this)`specifically targets the clicked accordion item.

Comment: @Yass @Mikkel-Madsen And for the sake of completeness, so does `event.target.id`.

Comment: @MikkelMadsen please mark the answer buddy.

Comment: Ye sorry :) It is marked, and thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this `accIcon.addClass("accordion-icon-active");` you are adding `accordion-icon-active` class to all of the `.accordion-icon` items. But you want to add that class to clicked item, so you should:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) { 
    $(this).find('.accordion-icon').addClass("accordion-icon-active"); 
}
```

Also note that this code :

```
accIcon.each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("accordion-icon-active");
});
```

is the same as:

```
accIcon.removeClass("accordion-icon-active");
```

iteration is not needed here, jquery takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You were setting the state of every icon on the page in your accordion-open click handler

I think it should be something more like this

```
$(".accordion-open").click(function() { 
  $('.accordion-icon').each(function(i, elem) {
    console.log(elem);
    $(elem).removeClass("accordion-icon-active");
  });

  if ($(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
    var accIcon = $(this).find(".accordion-icon");
    accIcon.addClass("accordion-icon-active");
  }
});
```

Clicking on each accordion icon now just sets the state of the one icon.